# Are casts a sign of bad design?

Tags: java, design-patterns, casting

I have this situation:

```
public abstract class ClassA{

    public ClassA getClassOfSameKind(){
        return this.getClass().newInstance();
    }

}

public abstract class ClassB extends ClassA{

    public void doSomethingSpecial(){
        ClassB otherClass = (ClassB) this.getClassOfSameKind();
        //do something special that only Class B can do
    }

}
```

Would you do it differently?

Comment: You're lucky this doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: typecasts are not inherently a sign of bad design.

Comment: This is likely bad design, but there are no casts in it.  You haven't told us enough of the problem you're trying to solve for us to tell you what we'd do differently.

Comment: I wonder how @BrianRoach knows what the OP thinks. And Don Roby, the code does contain a cast ...

Comment: Apologies, it does in fact contain a cast.  The rest of my comment stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cast can be avoided with a covariant return type:

```
public abstract class ClassA{

    public abstract ClassA getClassOfSameKind();

}

public abstract class ClassB extends ClassA{

    @Override
    public abstract ClassB getClassOfSameKind();

    public void doSomethingSpecial(){
        ClassB otherClass = this.getClassOfSameKind();
        //do something special that only Class B can do
    }

}

public class ClassC extends ClassB {
    @Override
    public ClassC getClassOfSameKind() {
        return new ClassC();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is objectively better than my original design, since the casting is separated into another method. Moderators don't take enough time to think about some questions...

Comment: @LayGonzález - 1) it is not **objectively** better.  Every leaf class now has to implement this method.  Ergo duplicate code - violates the DRY principle.  2) it wasn't moderators who voted to close.  3) the reason for the vote to close is that this question CANNOT have an objectively correct answer because there isn't one.

Comment: @StephenC Every leaf is a different class, therefore, every cast is different and there's no violation of the DRY principle. A moderator is someone that can moderate.

Comment: @LayGonzález - "A moderator is someone that can moderate".  Not on SO.  On SO a Moderator is someone who has a blue diamond next to their name.  They can do things that a high rep member can't do.  Like *override* votes to close, suspend people, etcetera.

Comment: @LayGonzález - DRY means don't repeat yourself.  All of those overloads are simply repeating themselves.  Your original version proves that the repetition is not necessary.

Comment: @StephenC 1)Thanks for letting me know about moderators. 2)But then, on every leaf class, every time you get an object by calling the getClassOfSameKind you would have to do a manual casting, which is worst according to the DRY principle.

Comment: @LayGonzález - did I say that my solution was objectively better?  No!  What I said was that there is NO objectively best solution.  And certainly not when you start to generalize.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid that typecast then you could write it as this:

```
public void doSomethingSpecial(){
    ClassB otherClass = this.getClass().newInstance();
    // ...
}
```

... or other ways.

But to be honest, I wouldn't bother unless the code contains *a large number* of calls to the `getClassOfSameKind()` method that require the typecast.

---

> Are casts a sign of bad design?

IMO, No.  Certainly, not in general.

In some cases they are, particularly when the typecast is hardwiring an assumption that some object has a particular type without a sound basis.  For example:

```
private ClassB otherB;

public void setOther(ClassA other) {
    this.otherB = (ClassB) otherB;  // It's always a ClassB.  She'll be right ...
}
```